# How to perform a Local Logout when the SAML2 idP does not support logging out?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I am trying to integrate our ASP.NET MVC website as a service provider to allow users to authenticate against a third-party SAML2 idP. I'm using the SustainSys.Saml2.Owin (2.3.0) nuget package.

I have the login process working, but logging the user out is proving to be more difficult.

The third-party running the idP is saying that they do not support logout, and that we must log the user out of our application ourselves. They are asking us to "create a new session" and to "do a local logout".

I should point out that this is made all the more difficult by us not having access to the idP or the web browsers testing is being carried out on, and the idP is run by an entity that doesn't speak English, so all communication and testing goes via a third-party translator...

Is is really possible that they don't support logout, or is something being lost in translation? I believe that the SAML2 idP is handled by some Oracle code/service in a bespoke corporate website.

The Logout action on our AccountController is as follows:

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SAML.Enabled"] == "false")
            {
                AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                // Having SAML2 enabled doesn't mean the user was logged in via SAML, but this seems to
                // handle that case and do the logout properly
                return Redirect("~/SAML2/Logout");
            }
        }
```

If I am not actually supposed to redirect to SAML2/Logout because they claim they don't support it, how do I ensure that any cookies in the client's browser are cleared?

In testing, when the next user accesses the site in the same browser, our application seems to know they're not logged in, and presents the login options. If they click the button to authenticate with the idP, they appear to be taken to the idP and then bounced back almost immediately, authenticated as the previous user? How do I stop that?

Edit: I should note that the idP's metadata does describe two SingleLogoutService, one HTTP-POST and one-HTTP-Redirect, which makes me think they do support logout of some kind. But when I redirect the client to ~/Saml2/Logout it results in an error page on the idP website, and no one can tell me why. I have not given them our public key - they said it "was not required".